# Webrtc for one to many/broadcast using node.js

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I got this code from the following website  http://asher2003.wordpress.com/2013/11/18/webrtc-code-example/

the html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<meta name='keywords' content='WebRTC, HTML5, JavaScript' />
<meta name='description' content='WebRTC Reference App' />
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width,initial-scale=1,minimum-scale=1,maximum-scale=1'>

<base target='_blank'>

<title>WebRTC client</title>

<!-- <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/main.css' /> -->

</head>

<body>

<div id='container'>

  <div id='videos'>
    <video id='localVideo' autoplay muted></video>
    <video id='remoteVideo' autoplay></video>
  </div>

</div>

<script src='/socket.io/socket.io.js'></script>
<script src='js/main.js'></script>

</body>
</html>
```

The server.js file

```
var static = require('node-static');
var http = require('http');
var file = new(static.Server)();
var app = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  file.serve(req, res);
}).listen(2013);

var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket){

    function log(){
        var array = [">>> Message from server: "];
      for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        array.push(arguments[i]);
      }
        socket.emit('log', array);
    }

    socket.on('message', function (message) {
        log('Got message: ', message);
    // For a real app, should be room only (not broadcast)
        socket.broadcast.emit('message', message);
    });

    socket.on('create or join', function (room) {
        var numClients = io.sockets.clients(room).length;

        log('Room ' + room + ' has ' + numClients + ' client(s)');
        log('Request to create or join room', room);

        if (numClients == 0){
            socket.join(room);
            socket.emit('created', room);
        } else if (numClients == 1) {
            io.sockets.in(room).emit('join', room);
            socket.join(room);
            socket.emit('joined', room);
        } else { // max two clients
            socket.emit('full', room);
        }
        socket.emit('emit(): client ' + socket.id + ' joined room ' + room);
        socket.broadcast.emit('broadcast(): client ' + socket.id + ' joined room ' + room);

    });

});
```

This works fine for one to one video conference.But how do I convert this for a broadcast/one to many?

I tried changing the above line

```
} else if (numClients == 1) {
                io.sockets.in(room).emit('join', room);
                socket.join(room);
                socket.emit('joined', room);
```

to numClients==2 but it didnt work.Nothing appeared on the screen

**UPDATE**
I have this in my main.js

```
function handleRemoteStreamAdded(event) {
  console.log('Remote stream added.');
  remoteVideo.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(event.stream);
  remoteStream = event.stream;
}
```

So the above function changes to

```
function handleRemoteStreamAdded(event){
remoteVideo = document.createElement('video');
if(document.getElementById( "remoteVideos" ).childNodes.length == 0){
    remoteVideo.setAttribute('id','remoteVideo1');
} else {
    remoteVideo.setAttribute('id','remoteVideo2');
}
document.getElementById( "remoteVideos" ).appendChild(remoteVideo);
remoteVideo.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(event.stream);
remoteVideo.play();

}
```

**UPDATE2**

[image]

I get this error..

Answer (score 1):

Its because

```
io.sockets.in(room).emit('join', room);
```

calls one socket connection(client) already being created, but when you have `numClients == 2`
means that you need to tell two other clients to send their information.

So, use

```
var clients = io.sockets.clients(room);
clients.forEach(function(client){
    client.emit('join', room);
    client.join(room);
    client.emit('joined', room);
});
```

This should do the trick.

Even on the html
replace

```
<video id='remoteVideo' autoplay></video>
```

with

```
<div id="remoteVideos"></div>
```

and on the handle remote stream in the main.js or in the js where you have used you webrtc client find the function where you instantiate the remote video and in my case the name of the  function is `handleRemoteStreamAdded` and add the following.

```
remoteVideo = document.createElement('video');
if(document.getElementById( "remoteVideos" ).childNodes.length == 0){
    remoteVideo.setAttribute('id','remoteVideo1');
} else {
    remoteVideo.setAttribute('id','remoteVideo2');
}
document.getElementById( "remoteVideos" ).appendChild(remoteVideo);
remoteVideo.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(event.stream);
remoteVideo.play();
```

Comment: Thnx for the reply..Should I add it to the else loop?i.e here` else if (numClients == 1) {
                io.sockets.in(room).emit('join', room);
                socket.join(room);
                socket.emit('joined', room);`????

Comment: So does my code become like this now `else if (numClients == 1) {
   var clients = io.sockets.clients(room);
   clients.forEach(client, function(client){
   client.emit('join', room);
  });
   socket.join(room);
   socket.emit('joined', room);
`

Comment: I have modified the forEach statement, it was a simple syntax problem.

Comment: Could you add it too my code above in your answer?cause i dont know whether it is in the if loop or not..

Comment: I have added the function in my question above that you told me to edit.Do I need to add it to that or clear all the contents in that and add your code?

Comment: Just check my edit...Also what did you mean  by this `Even on the html replace with`

Comment: I am sorry dude, check it out now.

Comment: no probs man...But the function that i have in my update above needs to be updated the way i have shown above?

Comment: I did as you said.But I get this error.I have added the image of the error above in my question.This throws the error `function handleUserMedia(stream) {
  console.log('Adding local stream.');
  localVideo.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
  localStream = stream;
  sendMessage('got user media');
  if (isInitiator) {
    maybeStart();
  }
}`